# Как написать регулярное выражение: имя английское от 2 до 7 длинной?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как написать регулярку имя английское от 2 до 7 длинной?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А Вам точно нужна регулярка?

Но с другой стороны. Я бы написал такую - `regex = /[A-Z][a-z]{1,6}/m;` - первая буква в верхнем регистре, дальше маленькие. Если нужно просто 2-7 длинной без учета регистра, то где то так `regex = /[a-z]{2,7}/mi;`

Answer (score 3):

Предполагает, что имя должно начинаться с большой буквы и может содержать апостроф или дефис:

```
^[A-Z]{1}[a-z-']{1,6}$
```